# Querying when data changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with product, cost, date for every day of the year  eg

```
prod1, 1, 01/01/2020    
prod1, 1, 02/01/2020    
prod1, 2, 03/01/2020   
prod1, 2, 04/01/2020   
prod1, 1, 05/01/2020  
prod1, 1, 06/01/2020
```

how can I generate a query to produce me the product, the cost and the date each one appears first and last in sequence for EVERY change ie not

```
prod1, 1, 01/01/2020 first, 06/01/2020 last 
prod1, 2, 03/01/2020 first, 04/01/2020 last
```

but

```
prod1, 1, 01/01/2020 first, 01/01/2020 last 
prod1, 2, 02/01/2020 first, 04/01/2020 last 
prod1, 1, 05/01/2020 first, 06/01/2020 last
```

I know it must be something to do with an OVER clause but am struggling with how that is working for me

NB there are multiple products

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select product, cost, min(date) first_date, max(date) last_date
from (
  select product, cost, date, 
    countif(cost_changed) over(partition by product order by date) grp
  from (
    select product, cost, date, 
      cost != lag(cost) over(partition by product order by date) cost_changed 
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
group by product, cost, grp
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

You can test, play with above using below CTE

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'prod1' as product, 1 as cost, DATE '2020-01-01' as date union all
  select 'prod1', 1, '2020-01-02' union all
  select 'prod1', 2, '2020-01-03' union all
  select 'prod1', 2, '2020-01-04' union all
  select 'prod1', 1, '2020-01-05' union all
  select 'prod1', 1, '2020-01-06'
)
```

Comment: did you have chance to try?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be ok:

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 'prod1' as product, 1 as cost, DATE '2020-01-01' as date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'prod1', 2, '2020-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'prod1', 2, '2020-01-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'prod1', 2, '2020-01-04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'prod1', 1, '2020-01-05' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'prod1', 1, '2020-01-06'
),
annotated AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    IF(cost != IFNULL(LAG(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY date), -1), date, NULL) AS first,
    IF(cost != IFNULL(LEAD(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY date), -1), date, NULL) AS last,
  FROM test_data
),
calculated AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    IFNULL(last, LEAD(last) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY date)) AS last_calculated
  FROM annotated
  WHERE first IS NOT NULL OR last IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
  product,
  cost,
  first,
  last_calculated AS last
FROM calculated 
WHERE first IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Had to make a few tweaks for the BigQuery format but works a treat - thank you so much